# Finding effective size of CListCtrl within minimized MFC window

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

In my MFC app, the user can minimize a window that has a CListCtrl inside. I need to know how many visible items the list control will be showing once the user restores the window.

The first implementation used `GetCountPerPage`. This was working great until we noticed the minimized window case and found it was returning zero.

I've also tried `GetClientRect`, `GetWindowRect` and `GetWindowPlacement` (using `rcNormalPosition`) to attempt to figure out the size of the CListCtrl so I can compute the page count manually. All these APIs return empty rectangles positioned at various offscreen locations.

What's the best way to figure out what the CListCtrl's height will be once I restore the window? Surely the real window rectangle is available somehow.

Comment: `GetCountPerPage` should not fail unless you are in icon view or something. When the window is minimized (or iconized) `GetCountPerPage` and `GetClientRect` will return the same numbers. The only difference is that there is no paint message. Maybe you are resizing the control or something. Some minimal code would help.

Comment: We are using a very big CListCtrl subclass which I can't share... so a minimal example can't be provided. But I am sure it doesn't do anything intentionally on window minimization.

Comment: I have to guess then... Maybe you are overriding `OnSize`. On first call, `HWND` of `ListView` may not be available so you get strange results for invalid window. For resizing window's children, check main window's `GetClientRect`, if width/height is zero then don't do anything because it's minimized.

Answer (score 0):

CListCtrl is a wrapper around list view control. To work with it directly you can try to use macros ListView_GetCountPerPage(...) which is basically sending  LVM_GETCOUNTPERPAGE message. If that still returns zero, this behavior is probably by default or it's a bug in common controls implementation. If your listview cannot change size in minimized state, you can probably just remember last valid value before window gets minimized.

Comment: The returning-zero behavior is what Win32 does by default. It's not MFC specific. I don't want to have to hook the window minimize but I haven't come up with anything more elegant.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because it's just strange. I would try to verify it with default list view, not with your subclassed version.

Answer (score 0):

Once the window is restored/minimized/shown/hidden, [WM_SHOWWINDOW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632645.aspx) will be called. So you can use this message to invoke [OnShowWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e457fh9.aspx) and find the counts/height of the clistctrl.